# How to create image from screenshot and send to message interface

Tags: objective-c, ios7, screenshot

I am very new to Objective-C. I am attempting to create an image from a screen shot and send it to the message interface to be sent as a message. I have looked at numerous Stackoverflow questions and one suggests use of `snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates` which is new in iOS 7. It returns a `UIView` pointer but I do not understand how to make an image from that and then to the message interface to be sent as a message. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: google `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, self.view.opaque, 0.0);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();   
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();    
NSData *newPNG=UIImagePNGRepresentation(img); // or you can use JPG or PDF
```

To share the image, then you can use `UIActivityViewController`:

```
UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"I would like to share it.",newPNG, nil] applicationActivities:nil];
activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[ UIActivityTypeMessage ,UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll];
[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 2):

This is you you get UIImage from screen:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);
[self drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```